# Find the number of Colleges offering Combinations of Levels: Performance

Tags: c#, performance, linq, entity-framework

I have been using entity framework 5 as DataAccess layer for my application.
I have a case where there are a set of `Levels` offered. And I have a set of `Colleges` offering the `Levels`.

**Level :**

```
public partial class Level
    {
        public Level()
        {

        }

        public int LevelID { get; set; }
        public string LevelCode { get; set; }
        public string LevelName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> LevelDisplayOrder { get; set; }
        public bool IsHigherEducation { get; set; }

    }
```

**CollegePrograms :**

```
public partial class CollegeProgram
    {
        public int CollegeUniversityProgramID { get; set; }
        public int CollegeID { get; set; }
        public int ProgramID { get; set; }

       public virtual College College { get; set; }

       }
```

**Program :**

```
public partial class Program
    {
        public Program()
        {

            this.CollegePrograms = new HashSet<CollegeProgram>();

        }

        public int ProgramID { get; set; }
        public string ProgramCode { get; set; }
        public string ProgramName { get; set; }
        public string Alias { get; set; }
        public int LevelID { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<CollegeProgram> CollegePrograms { get; set; }
        public virtual Level Level { get; set; }

    }
```

Now I need to find the number of colleges offering Combinations of Levels e.g. 'Bachelor Only', 'Master Only', 'Phd Only', 'Bachelor and Master Only', 'Bachelor and Phd only', 'Bachelor and Master and Phd Only', 'Master and Phd Only'.

This is the code I have written, and it is causing a large impact on performance. How can I enhance its performance?

```
 public CollegeCountReportBDTO GetCollegeReportProgramCombination(int fiscalYearID, int? levelId = null)
        {
            var collegeCountReport = new CollegeCountReportBDTO();
            try
            {
                var fiscalYear = Database.FiscalYears.FirstOrDefault(o => o.FiscalYearID == fiscalYearID);
                if (fiscalYear != null)
                {
                    var universities = Database.Universities.Where(o => o.Active).AsEnumerable();
                    var collegeTypes = Database.CollegeTypes.Where(o => o.Active).AsEnumerable();
                    var regions = Database.Regions.Where(o => o.Active).AsEnumerable();
                    var levels = Database.Levels.Where(o => o.Active && o.IsHigherEducation && levelId == null || o.LevelID == levelId);

                    var levelCombinationIds = (from level in levels select level.LevelID).ToList().GetPowerSet();
                    levelCombinationIds = levelCombinationIds.Where(o => o.Any());

                    #region "Headers

                    collegeCountReport.CollegeTypes = collegeTypes.Select(o => new CollegeType()
                    {
                        Active = o.Active,
                        CollegeTypeCode = o.CollegeTypeCode,
                        CollegeTypeID = o.CollegeTypeID,
                        CollegeTypeName = o.CollegeTypeName,
                        CreatedBy = o.CreatedBy,
                        CreatedDate = o.CreatedDate,
                        ModifiedBy = o.ModifiedBy,
                        ModifiedDate = o.ModifiedDate,
                        Remarks = o.Remarks
                    }).ToList();
                    collegeCountReport.Universities = universities.ToList();
                    collegeCountReport.Regions = regions.ToList();
                    string name;
                    string ids;
                    List<Level> levelList;

                    foreach (var levelIds in levelCombinationIds)
                    {
                        if (!levelIds.Any())
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        name = string.Empty;
                        ids = string.Empty;
                        levelList = new List<Level>();

                        foreach (var level in levelIds.Select(id => levels.FirstOrDefault(o => o.LevelID == id)))
                        {
                            name += level.LevelName + ",";
                            ids = level.LevelID + ", ";
                            levelList.Add(level);
                        }
                        name = name.Length > 0 ? name.Substring(0, name.Length - 1) : name;
                        collegeCountReport.LevelCombination.Add(new LevelCombinationBDTO
                        {
                            Levels = levelList,
                            Name = name,
                            Ids = ids,
                            IsExplicitCount = false
                        });
                        if (!levelId.HasValue)
                        {
                            collegeCountReport.LevelCombination.Add(new LevelCombinationBDTO
                                                                        {
                                                                            Levels = levelList,
                                                                            Name = name + " only",
                                                                            Ids = ids,
                                                                            IsExplicitCount = true,
                                                                        });
                        }
                    }

                    #endregion "Headers

                    var collegesCount = FindAll(o => o.Active && o.EstablishedDate <= fiscalYear.EndDate).AsEnumerable();

                    #region "Value Generation"

                    foreach (var levelCombination in collegeCountReport.LevelCombination)
                    {
                        collegesCount = levelCombination.IsExplicitCount
                            ? collegesCount.Where(o => levelCombination.Levels.UnorderedEqual((from collegeProgram in o.CollegeUniversityPrograms.Where(p => p.Active).DistinctBy(q => q.Program.Level) select collegeProgram.Program.Level).ToList()))
                            : collegesCount.Where(o => (!levelCombination.Levels.Except(from collegeProgram in o.CollegeUniversityPrograms.Where(p => p.Active).ToList() select collegeProgram.Program.Level).Any()));

                        if (collegesCount.Any())
                        {
                            foreach (var university in universities)
                            {
                                foreach (var collegeType in collegeTypes)
                                {
                                    foreach (var region in regions)
                                    {
                                        var tempColleges = collegesCount;
                                        tempColleges = tempColleges.Where(o =>
                                                o.UniversityID == university.UniversityID
                                                && o.CollegeTypeID == collegeType.CollegeTypeID
                                                && o.MunicipalityVdc.District.Zone.RegionID == region.RegionID
                                                );
                                        if (tempColleges.Any())
                                        {
                                            collegeCountReport.LevelCombinationCollegeStatisticalReportBdto.Add(new LevelCombinationCollegeStatisticalReportBDTO
                                            {
                                                University = university,
                                                CollegeType = collegeType,
                                                Region = region,
                                                LevelCombinationBDTO = levelCombination,
                                                CollegeCount = tempColleges.Count()
                                            });
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    #endregion "Value Generation"
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (ex.HandleException(Constants.BAL_POLICY))
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return collegeCountReport;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check your indentation, it's pretty rough. You should stick to the standard :

```
class MyClass
{
    //some code
        //some nested code
}
```

Your `levels` variable, being an `IQueryable<T>` (I think, using `var` makes it hard to review), has its execution defered, and you call it twice. Which means you'll have two database queries for nothing. You should do as you did with the rest of the variables and add `AsEnumerable` at the end of your query.